# Galleria toggle description only?

Tags: jquery, galleria

```
<div id="galleria">
    <img src="/img/pic1.jpg" data-title="title1" data-description="Et facilisis non. Sed, augue turpis eu, vel pellentesque aliquam, tristique ac, tincidunt placerat! Lundium, adipiscing et porttitor velit! Rhoncus adipiscing amet egestas, non dictumst.">
    <img src="/img/pic2.jpg" data-title="title2" data-description="Turpis enim elementum ac nisi magna tempor, aliquam, auctor tincidunt, scelerisque pellentesque parturient velit! Dolor et risus scelerisque vel augue nec, vel. Elementum in! Pid.">
</div>
```

I have this type of mark up where images has very long description so they don't need to be shown all the time so I want to use Galleria's default `galleria-info-link` to toggle just description so the title stays all the time and users can toggle description.

Try to change function to only toggle description but since Galleria automatically assign (display:block) to each `info-title` and `info-description` , it doesn't work as expected.

Will there be any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the div id=galleria try this :

```
<style>
.img_field span {
    display: none;
}

<div class='img_field'>
    <img .... />
    <span> Your description here </span>
</div>

<script>
    $('.img_field').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children('span').show();
    });
    $('.img_field').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('span').hide();
    });
</script>
```